# Is there any way to offload memory with TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have this method inside a class that prepares the data and trains on it inside the same method, each time the method gets called my memory usage grows around 200MB, this makes the script unable to train for long periods of time in the best cases it trains for 8-9 times before running out of memory, I tried commenting the `load_weights` section but this is not the source of the problem I also tried using `model.fit` without the callbacks but this does seem to solve the issue basically I tried commenting every line in this method but the memory usage keeps growing, in another script that trains on random numbers with a while loop it does not fill the memory, so I am pretty sure that this method has something wrong that keeps adding data to the memory without clearing it, I tried using `gc.collect()` but it does not help at all.

why does this happen and how to go about fixing this?

```
def make_data(self):
    if not os.path.exists("/py_stuff/BIN_API_v3/python-binance-master/"+str(self.coin)):
        os.makedirs("/py_stuff/BIN_API_v3/python-binance-master/"+str(self.coin))


    checkpoint_filepath ="/py_stuff/BIN_API_v3/python-binance-master/"+str(self.coin)+"/check_point"
    weights_checkpoint = "/py_stuff/BIN_API_v3/python-binance-master/"+str(self.coin)


    checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_filepath)


    model_checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        filepath=checkpoint_filepath,
        save_weights_only=True,
        mode='max',
        save_best_only=True,
        verbose=1)



    dataset_train = self.df.tail(400)
    training_set = dataset_train.iloc[:, 1:2].values

    print (dataset_train.tail(5)) 

    sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
    training_set_scaled = sc.fit_transform(training_set)

    X_train = []
    y_train = []
    for i in range(10, 400):
        X_train.append(training_set_scaled[i-10:i, 0])
        y_train.append(training_set_scaled[i, 0])
    X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)
    X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))

    ST = time.time() 

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(units = 128, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 1)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(LSTM(units=128 , return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(LSTM(units=128 , return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(LSTM(units=128))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(units=1 ))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error' , metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])

    ## loading weights 

    try:
        model.load_weights(checkpoint_filepath)
        print ("Weights loaded successfully $$$$$$$ ")
    except:
        print ("No Weights Found !!! ")



    model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=20,batch_size=50, callbacks=[model_checkpoint_callback])



    ### saving model conf and weights 

    try:
      #  model.save(checkpoint_filepath)
        model.save_weights(filepath=checkpoint_filepath)

        print ("Saving weights and model done ")

    except OSError as no_model:
        print ("Error saving weights and model !!!!!!!!!!!! ")

    print (time.time() - ST)

    self.model = model 
  #   tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
    return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the model is recreated every time the function is called. Tensorflow does not release a model from memory until the session is restarted (tf < 2.0) or the script itself is rerun (any tf version).

You should create your model outside the function (preferably in the `__init__` method and use it in your function for training:

```
def __init__(self):
    ....
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(units = 128, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 1)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(LSTM(units=128 , return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(LSTM(units=128 , return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(LSTM(units=128))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(units=1 ))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error' , metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])
    self.model = model

def make_data(self):
    ....
    ST = time.time() 

    model = self.model

    ## loading weights 

    try:
        model.load_weights(checkpoint_filepath)
        print ("Weights loaded successfully $$$$$$$ ")
    except:
        print ("No Weights Found !!! ")
    ....
```

Comment: I wrote a file with two functions one of them prepares the data and the second one has the model layout and I imported that file to the main file that had the method mentioned above and it calls the functions but I still encounter the same problem with the memory it just keeps on growing

Comment: The gist is, you cannot use a function that recreates the model every time. You should create the model once throughout your entire program, and pass it around (even across files).